# struct.error_ unpack requires a buffer of 8 bytes

Tags: python, python-3.x

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uaRfL.jpg)

I am running a mapping program using cartopy and I got this error message for the shapefile.py, what can I do to fix it ? I tried to revert to Python3.8 as the person who wrote the code suggested but that doesn't help either.

```
(venv_with_python3.8) lnx@lnx-System-Product-Name:~/Desktop/globus$ python3 globus.py
2022-10-08 14:57:29,347 start
/home/lnx/virtual_env/venv_with_python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/shapely/geometry/base.py:250: ShapelyDeprecationWarning: Setting the 'coords' to mutate a Geometry in place is deprecated, and will not be possible any more in Shapely 2.0
  super().__setattr__(name, value)
2022-10-08 14:57:32,114 reading the land polygons
2022-10-08 14:57:32,571 marking the ocean on axes 0
2022-10-08 14:57:47,094 marking the ocean on axes 1
2022-10-08 14:57:56,265 marking the ocean on axes 2
2022-10-08 14:58:11,742 marking the ocean on axes 3
2022-10-08 14:58:18,259 marking the ocean on axes 4
2022-10-08 14:58:24,119 marking the ocean on axes 5
2022-10-08 14:58:34,041 projecting the raster map on axes 0
2022-10-08 14:58:35,313 projecting the raster map on axes 1
2022-10-08 14:58:36,484 projecting the raster map on axes 2
2022-10-08 14:58:36,574 projecting the raster map on axes 3
2022-10-08 14:58:36,638 projecting the raster map on axes 4
2022-10-08 14:58:36,721 projecting the raster map on axes 5
2022-10-08 14:58:36,791 reading features
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "globus.py", line 495, in <module>
    main()
  File "globus.py", line 468, in main
    axes.add_features()
  File "globus.py", line 236, in add_features
    borders = reader.ReadBorders()
  File "/home/lnx/Desktop/globus/reader.py", line 310, in ReadBorders
    b.geometry for b in ReadRecords('shapes/ne_10m_admin_0_boundary_lines_land')
  File "/home/lnx/Desktop/globus/reader.py", line 209, in ReadRecords
    return list(shapereader.Reader(name).records())
  File "/home/lnx/virtual_env/venv_with_python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cartopy/io/shapereader.py", line 167, in records
    for shape_record in self._reader.iterShapeRecords():
  File "/home/lnx/virtual_env/venv_with_python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/shapefile.py", line 1771, in iterShapeRecords
    for shape, record in izip(self.iterShapes(), self.iterRecords(fields=fields)):
  File "/home/lnx/virtual_env/venv_with_python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/shapefile.py", line 1483, in iterShapes
    shape = self.__shape(oid=i, bbox=bbox)
  File "/home/lnx/virtual_env/venv_with_python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/shapefile.py", line 1309, in __shape
    (recNum, recLength) = unpack(">2i", f.read(8))
struct.error: unpack requires a buffer of 8 bytes
(venv_with_python3.8) lnx@lnx-System-Product-Name:~/Desktop/globus$
```

And the code from shapefile.py at line 1309 is :

```
(recNum, recLength) = unpack(">2i", f.read(8))
        # Determine the start of the next record
        next = f.tell() + (2 * recLength)
        shapeType = unpack("<i", f.read(4))[0]
        record.shapeType = shapeType
        # For Null shapes create an empty points list for consistency
        if shapeType == 0:
            record.points = []
        # All shape types capable of having a bounding box
        elif shapeType in (3,5,8,13,15,18,23,25,28,31):
            record.bbox = _Array('d', unpack("<4d", f.read(32)))
            # if bbox specified and no overlap, skip this shape
            if bbox is not None and not bbox_overlap(bbox, record.bbox):
                # because we stop parsing this shape, skip to beginning of
                # next shape before we return
                f.seek(next)
                return None
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow, please [take a tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and see [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as for your question "WE DON'T KNOW", we aren't sitting next to you, you need to provide the code as text not a picture, so that someone can copy it and paste it in his computer with all the necessary steps to duplicate the problem on his pc, so people can answer your question, please edit your question to provide all the required information.

Comment: most likely the file you are reading from is empty or corrupted, you should check the file.

Comment: The *f.read()* function reads **at most** 8 bytes. If there are fewer than 8 bytes available that's what it will return. Best practice would be to try the read and then check how many bytes were actually returned. Also, the shadowing of the built-in *next* function could cause all sorts of issues